# Poles of $(e^z+1)^{-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I know the function $(e^z+1)^{-1}$ has a pole at the points $(1+2n)\pi i$. How do I show this pole is simple (i.e order 1)? I have attempted to multiply the above by $(z- i \pi)$ and show that the resulting function is holomorphic, however that has not been particularly fruitful. Does anyone have any advice? Will I have to compute a Laurent series? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Theorem**.  If $p$ and $q$ are holomorphic at $z_0$ and $p(z_0)\ne0$ and $q(z_0)=0$ and $q'(z_0)\ne0$, then $p/q$ has a simple pole at $z_0$.

Comment: I assume this can be proven using the argument principle?

Comment: I would just use L'Hopital.

Comment: @rubikscube09 alternatively, use that you can write $q(z) = (z-z_0)f$, where $f$ is holomorphic and nonvanishing at $z_0$, then that $1/f$ is again holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Why not fruitful ?? Let $f(z)=(e^z+1)^{-1}$ , $g(z)=e^z+1$ and $z_n=(1+2n)\pi i$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Then $(z-z_n)f(z)= \frac{z-z_n}{g(z)-g(z_n)} \to g'(z_n)^{-1}=-1 \ne 0$ as $z \to z_n$.

This shows that each $z_n$ is a simple pole of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\frac{z-i\pi}{e^z+1} $ is the reciprocal of a difference quotient. Take the limit of this difference quotient to see that you get the derivative of $e^z$ at $i\pi$ which is simply $e^{i\pi}$ since $e^z$ is its own derivative.

Answer (score 0):

The function has a pole **iff** it is a zero of $e^z+1$.

Note that the derivative is $e^z$ hence any zero is simple hence the pole is simple.

Comment: Why does the derivative being $e^z$ guarantee the pole is simple?

Comment: If the pole had order greater than one then the zero would have order greater than one and hence the derivative would have a zero there too.